# Can we approximates any real continuous function on a compact $[0,T]$ by a step function uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f: \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R$ continuous.

Can we find a sequence of step functions that goes uniformly to $f$ on any compact $[0,T]$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you need to assume $f$ is continuous, as in the title.

Then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,T]$. Let $\epsilon>0$. If $\delta>0$ is such that [etc] then you can find a step function with steps of horizontal width $\delta$...